# AJAX how to extract data return

Tags: javascript

as you see i have a ajax code pass data to server and return result include id,name,quantity.

How to get quantity or id or name only and print ? thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#bto_update_quantity").click(function (){
            $.ajax({
                url:"cart/update_quantity",
                type:"get",
                dataType:"text",
                data : {
                     id : $('.frm_product_id_cart').text(),
                     name : $('.frm_product_name_cart').text(),
                     quantity : $('#frm_product_quantity_cart').val()                   
                },
                success : function()
                {
                    $('#frm_product_quantity_cart').val()
                }});
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dataType` `JSON` instead of `text`.

```
$("#bto_update_quantity").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: "cart/update_quantity",
         type: "get",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {
             id: $('.frm_product_id_cart').text(),
             name: $('.frm_product_name_cart').text(),
             quantity: $('#frm_product_quantity_cart').val()
         },
         success: function (data) {
             var id = data.id;
             var name = data.name;
             var quantity = data.quantity;
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

your dataType should be Json and not a Text.

you should pass a return param in success function

*success : function(data)*

try to console log the data  and you would know how to get your desired values

Answer (score 0):

If result is object.
You can do:

```
$("#bto_update_quantity").click(function (){
        $.ajax({
            url:"cart/update_quantity",
            type:"get",
            dataType:"text",
            data : {
                 id : $('.frm_product_id_cart').text(),
                 name : $('.frm_product_name_cart').text(),
                 quantity : $('#frm_product_quantity_cart').val()                   
            },
            success : function(result)
            {
                console.log(result.quantity);
            }});
    });
```